# Are there any open datasets with technical specifications for photographic equipment?

Tags: data-request, linked-data

I want to set up a free service where photographers buying or searching for discontinued photographic equipment can reference for technical specifications.  For instance, most eBay-listings of second-hand equipment are without any tech. specs whatsoever.  My current plan is to do this for the mainstream, usable cameras, lenses and flash units - i.e. not collectibles.

Information about *current* equipment is usually available from the manufacturer's websites, and some manufacturers (e.g. [Canon Camera Museum](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/)) also make information about older models available on-line.  I am aware of a few non-manufacturer resources such as [Botzilla](http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html) for strobe trigger voltages, and [Butkus](http://www.butkus.org/chinon/) for old manuals (which contains technical specifications).

By "technical specifications", I refer to things such as focal length and maximum f-stop (for lenses) and (normalized) guide number and trigger voltage (for flash units).

All the sites mentioned above as examples requires scraping to extract the data.

I am hunting for other non-manufacturer resources for technical specifications for photographic equipment to add to the planned service.  I am of course most interested in quality open linked data that does not require scraping or other ad-hoc data extraction methods.  However, since I suspect that few or no such resources exist, I am interested in pointers to *anything* useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's semi-abandoned, but there are various levels of details for 1,300 models here: https://www.freebase.com/digicams/digital_camera?instances

If nothing else, the schema might provide a starting point for informing the types of information to collect.

Comment: freebase.com has gone 404.

Comment: Yes, Freebase has been shut down, but the data dumps are available from https://developers.google.com/freebase/. There is also http://freebase-easy.cs.uni-freiburg.de/dump/ but unfortunately neither are as easy to use as the former online version.

Comment: At least the data is still there. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4):

Flickr might be an interesting source, though you'd need to scrape it too, probably starting off at http://www.flickr.com/cameras/. The specs are limited to a few key features, but you should find a lot of models there.